# How to add javascript data to mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have problem how to add this javascript data to mysql database?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var count = 0;

function countClicks() {    
 count = count +1 ;    
    document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = count;     
}    
</script>


<input type="button" value="Like "onclick="javascript:countClicks();" alt="alt text"/>    
<div id="likes">0</div>
```

Comment: [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: you can do that with AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) while inserting your js code to mysql db. Assign your code string to a variable and use mysql-real-escape-string while inserting db. Example usage;

**HTML:**

```
<form action="save_code.php" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td><textarea name="code"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**PHP:** save_code.php

```
// Comment out this for real test
//$jsCode = $_POST['code'];

//Assign js code string to variable
$jsCode = '<script type="text/javascript">    
var count = 0;

function countClicks() {    
 count = count +1 ;    
    document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = count;     
}    
</script>


<input type="button" value="Like "onclick="javascript:countClicks();" alt="alt text"/>    
<div id="likes">0</div>';

$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    or die(mysql_error());

$query = "INSERT INTO your_table(id, code) VALUES('', mysql_real_escape_string($jsCode))";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: i'm a student.i'm try to do that but not work.i want to add my school project simple like system.if you have any script give me.thanx

Comment: If you are trying to get some code without any effort, you are in wrong place. Also you are in wrong way in your life. I suggest you learning something by yourself with researching

Comment: tnx,my js code also working but i cant adding js data to mysql database.im so tiered and i want to do that.thanx your honestly i'll do it myself.i'll do

Comment: If you provide what you tried so far in your question, stackoverflow family helps you better

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do:

1-  AJAX

You must make a SaveData.php for example and make a ajax Post to this page and then insert in database.

2- JS to PHP

In the same page you do this

```
Insert into TABLE (count) VALUES (".<script> write(count); </script>.");
```

Comment: sorry idont know ajax

Comment: Try the second answer

Comment: try to do that but no idea

Comment: Are you programming in PHP?

Comment: im student of web development